# Can't run google maps v2 on a real device

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make a simple app that shows google maps on my device. I run it in my Alcatel OT 990 android device (v. 2.2.2) but it shows the error message "Application has stopped unexpectedly.... then force close". I believe I'm doing everything right, since i follow the instructions from a youtube tutorial that works.
This is my code (I' ve included Android Support Library, Google Play Services Library and android.jar):

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
    android:name="com.xristina.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.xristina.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="*************my key here*********************"/>
</application>
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.xristina.maps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

Any ideas please??

Ι added the code suggested by @BBonDoo and the logcat result was:

```
02-06 16:59:34.807: W/dalvikvm(2735): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xristina.maps/com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.xristina.maps-2.apk]
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2051)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4645)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.xristina.maps-2.apk]
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
02-06 16:59:34.817: E/AndroidRuntime(2735):     ... 11 more
```

I also have to say that this code wasn't included in the tutorial i studied at
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRnEkP2q4fo  and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZRgiwGfvSQ

Comment: Did you use your debug key to get access to the api and turn on the feature in the apis console? https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: You did not finish writing the code to display Maps in your MainActivity.java. Please fill the code completely as shown in the my answer.

Comment: I will try what @BBonDoo has suggested and get back to you with the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Answer new ]...added update]**

Your Logcat is good. It means as follows;

Please look into two pictures and match your package name(①) with the correct one(②).

[image: This is your manifest file]

[image: This is your java file]

Please replace the package name in the manifest file with the package name in your java file.

It is correct code in your manifest file;

```
<Activity
     android:name="com.xristina.maps.MainActivity"
     ...
```

---

**[Answer old]**

You did not finish writing the code enough to display Google Maps in your MainActivity.java. Please fill your code with the code as shown in the below, which is the basic code you must know essentially in order to display the Google Maps in Android platform:

```
public class MianActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that, and get back as sook as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Please, take a look at my revised code when you get a chance. I made the changes you suggested but still can't manage to get a map in my mobile phone.

Comment: @user2044641..OK...I saw your revised code...Good..and your logcat is good...I found what the cause of your error was through your logcat...Please see this answer of mine which I added my solution..

Comment: @user2044641..Please read my answer again. I updated for you.

Comment: Thanks!!Problem solved. The only thing it says now is that I have to install Google Play, and when i try that it says that it's incompatible with my device. Do you know a way around this??

Comment: @user2044641..yap, I know well...To install Google Play is very easy. [This document(click here)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/google/play-services/setup.html) will let you know the right way.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything!! @BBonDoo

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777962/cant-get-google-map-to-show-behind-google-places-in-my-app[/link] I am trying to implement what you told me in another app, but can't make it work. The result is that I get Google Places, but not the map. @BBonDoo

Comment: @user2044641...I saw both your liked question and the original tutorial related to your question. That tutorial is old version before  the new Google Maps API version 2 appeared. I tried to test that tutorial last month, but the libraries changed and not applied in new Google Maps API v2.

Comment: Yes I am afraid you are right. Have you found anything new-updated? I am searching the web, but I think that a tutorial like this isn't still ready. Anyway thanks again for you time and take care! @BBonDoo

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="myApiKey"/>
```

This "myApiKey" is suppose to be the API Key you get from Google API Console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I did use my API key, just didn't put it here.