# Can't get google maps to show behind Google Places in my app (only grid)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I have this code from the tutorial [Android Working with Google Places and Maps](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/), and I want to change it, because I need it to work with google maps v2. The problem is that instead of the map, I only get a grid behind google places.

PlacesMapActivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class PlacesMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    // Nearest places
    PlacesList nearPlaces;

    // Map view
    MapView mapView;

    // Map overlay items
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    // Map controllers
    MapController mc;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    OverlayItem overlayitem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

        // Getting intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Users current geo location
        String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
        String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

        // Nearplaces list
        nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Geopoint to place on map
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

        // Map overlay item
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
                "That is you!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        // These values are used to get map boundary area
        // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // check for null in case it is null
        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
            // loop through all the places
            for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
                latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
                longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

                // Geopoint to place on map
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));

                // Map overlay item
                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                        place.vicinity);

                itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


                // calculating map boundary area
                minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
                minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
                maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
                maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            // showing all overlay items
            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
        }

        // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

        // Showing the center of the map
        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
        mapView.postInvalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

GooglePlaces.java

```
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class GooglePlaces {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    // Google API Key
    private static final String API_KEY = "****my key is here*****"; // my API key Key for browser apps 

    // Google Places search url's
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    private double _radius;

    /**
     * Searching places
     * @param latitude - latitude of place
     * @params longitude - longitude of place
     * @param radius - radius of searchable area
     * @param types - type of place to search
     * @return list of places
     * */
    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = 3000;

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @param refrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I 'm trying many things but can't get it to work, even though I managed to get google maps showing in my device in a different project. What do I have to change exactly?

my logcat

```
02-10 16:42:42.479: W/KeyCharacterMap(11974): Can't open keycharmap file
02-10 16:42:42.479: W/KeyCharacterMap(11974): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/ft5x02-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='ft5x02-touchscreen'
02-10 16:42:42.479: W/KeyCharacterMap(11974): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-10 16:42:54.067: D/Network(11974): Network Enabled
02-10 16:42:54.077: D/Your Location(11974): latitude:37.970373475, longitude: 23.772967
02-10 16:42:54.507: D/Places Status(11974): OK
02-10 16:42:57.917: D/Place(11974): Agora Ilission S.A.Chatzigianni Mexi 8, Athens, Greece21 0725 225237.97706123.751386
02-10 16:43:00.407: D/Place(11974): Piu VerdeΣτρατ. Αλ. Παπάγου, Athens, Greece21 0654 618537.99337223.794133
02-10 16:43:01.127: W/KeyCharacterMap(11974): Can't open keycharmap file
02-10 16:43:01.127: W/KeyCharacterMap(11974): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/ft5x02-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='ft5x02-touchscreen'
02-10 16:43:01.127: W/KeyCharacterMap(11974): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-10 16:43:02.497: W/MapActivity(11974): Recycling dispatcher com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@45202618
02-10 16:43:02.507: V/MapActivity(11974): Recycling map object.
02-10 16:43:02.617: I/MapActivity(11974): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
02-10 16:43:02.617: E/MapActivity(11974): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Manifest

Is Permission and Uses Library added like follow

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in `manifest` tag and

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in `application` tag

And Double check is your device able to connect to Internet.